# MapSingleType error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I create a project by MVC3 and use EFCode first for DataAccess Layer.

in my DataBase I have PackaginInfo Table, and in project I carete Package Class, 
this is my code:

```
public class Package
{
    public decimal PackageID { get; set; }
    public decimal Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public bool isFree { get; set; }

}


public class ParandShopsEntities : DbContext
{       

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Package>().MapSingleType().ToTable("PackagingInfo"); 

    }

    public DbSet<Package> PackagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

when i debug my project i get error: 
Error   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'MapSingleType' and no extension method 'MapSingleType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    E:\Projects\ein co\89-11-23\Parand\MvcApplication1\Models\ParandShopsEntities.cs

pls. help me

Answer (score 8):

In CTP5, you now just call

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Package>().ToTable("PackagingInfo");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when i try get data list, i get this error: The entity type Package is not part of the model for the current context. my method is :                                  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ParandShopsEntities _db = new ParandShopsEntities();
            var q = _db.PackagingInfo.ToList();
            return View();
        }

Comment: What is the code for your DbContext?  Is there more to the class Package that you're not telling us about, such as an enum (which is not supported)?

Comment: no i just have this code in my DBContext class

public class ParandShopEntities : DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<Package>      PackagingInfo  { get; set; }

        public ParandShopEntities()
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Package>().ToTable("tbl_PackagingInfo");         
            
        }

        
    }

Comment: I get this error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.tbl_PackagingInfo'. when I debug the project my connection string is: <connectionStrings> <add name="ParandShopsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ParandShops;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> </connectionStrings>

Comment: my problem was solved.
I Changed "ParnadShopEntities" Class 

 {
        public ParandShopEntities()
            : base("Data Source=192.168.0.100;Initial Catalog=ParandShops;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")//("ParandShopEntities")
        {
        }
       ...

Answer (score 3):

Or alternatively you can use *TableAttribute* data annotations:

```
[Table("PackagingInfo")]
public class Package
{
    public decimal PackageID { get; set; }
    public decimal Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public bool isFree { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when i try get data list, i get this error: The entity type Package is not part of the model for the current context. my method is :                                  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ParandShopsEntities _db = new ParandShopsEntities();
            var q = _db.PackagingInfo.ToList();
            return View();
        }

Comment: First off, your connection string is wrong, you don't need metadata information in the connection string when developing a Code First application. Your connection string should be look like this: <add name="ParandShopsEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ParandShops;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: thx a lot
my problem was solved.
I Changed "ParnadShopEntities" Class 

 {
        public ParandShopEntities()
            : base("Data Source=192.168.0.100;Initial Catalog=ParandShops;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")//("ParandShopEntities")
        {
        }
       ...

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is that you rebuilt all t4 templates. If you have changed navigation properties in the edmx file then you should rebuild your t4 templates, otherwise you may get this error.